# Import project into Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

Is there anyway to migrate individual projects and merge them into an existing instance of Sonar?

Background:

I've setup a new instance of Sonar by performing a normal backup and restore. Another team, also using Sonar, want to migrate their projects over to this new server as well. I'm now faced with a data merging problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. The best way to achieve this is to replay the project history by running Sonar analyses with the "-Dsonar.projectDate=xxxx-xx-xx" property.

For more information, take a look a the "sonar.projectDate" description on the ["Analysis Parameters" documentation page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters).

Comment: Is it possible with SonarQube 4.x?  I have set up a new instance with the latest Sonar, and have some projects that need moving across, with their history intact.  Failing that, could you elaborate on the answer you gave above, as it's unclear exactly what to do?

Comment: I added a link to the doc page that explains this.